# Will Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2 work with SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Microsofts Requirements and compatibility page for TFS found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) do not show Update 2 in the SQL section.

In our current environment we have TFS2017 Update 2 running on the same machine as SQL Server 2014.  I'd like to install SQL Server 2017 and move the TFS database off the same machine to the new instance of SQL then point TFS 2017 at the new instance.

The next weekend I would do the TFS upgrade from 2017 to 2018.  I have added extra context in case there is an obvious flaw in my plan that can be pointed out by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not support**

Please take a look at below Q&A

> Markus: *Does TFS 2017 support SQL Server 2017 as well?*
>
> Brian Harry MS: *@Markus, It does not. I believe **SQL 2017 shipped
>   after TFS 2017** and, therefore, support was not included. Here’s our
>   system requirements page:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements*
>
> *[Source Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/10/13/team-foundation-server-2018-and-sql-server/)*

Likewise, SQL 2017 also shipped after TFS2017 update2. According to [SQL Server 2017 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-2017-release-notes), generated released October 2017, TFS2017 update2 released July 24, 2017.

Besides according to [TFS 2017 Update 2 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2) also not mentioned support SQL2017

You could use SQL2016 (minimum SP1) instead which support on both TFS2017 update2/2018 as a workaround for now. When you upgrade to TFS2018, then update your SQL version to SQL2017.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2017 Update 2 isn't listed because the SQL Server requirements didn't change from Update 1. Thus, TFS 2017 Update 2 is not compatible with SQL Server 2017.

I would expect the configuration process would throw an error when attempting to attach the database.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs this information, when attempting to use Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64). TFS 2017 Update 2 returned the following error:

TF255146: The SQL Server instance you specified (XXXXXX) is version 'SQL Server vNext', which is not supported by this version of Team Foundation Server. For more information about supported versions of SQL Server, visit https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/requirements